# How to merge information from two tables with similar columns

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, merge

I have two almost similar tables in two different servers. These tables have similar columns and similar primary key. Due to some change I've done the content in theses table is little bit different. Now I'd like to merge or to equalize the data.

Table 1:

```
Id  UUTId   FixtId  Date       Verdict  SN  Batch   Location    
===========================================================================
17  87  8   2013-04-07  Pass    787307  DEBUG      AC
18  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    1234567 031684473  AC   
19  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678 031684473  AC   
20  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678 031684473  AC   
21  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678 031684473  AC
22  85  123 2013-05-17  Pass    4561237 753159456  AF
```

Table 2:

```
Id  UUTId   FixtId  Date       Verdict  SN    Batch   Location  
============================================================================
17  87  8   2013-04-07  Pass    787307    DEBUG      AC
18  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    1234567   031684473  AC 
19  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678   031684473  AC 
20  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678   031684473  AC 
21  84  10  2013-04-08  Pass    2345678   031684473  AC
27  185 23  2013-08-10  Pass    257O E456 753159456  AF
```

Last two rows are not similar in two tables and i want to merge all information to one table.
I can use SQL server 2012 or Python dbc tool

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be exactly the same and you have a linkserver connection, truncate one of the tables and select back into it from the other.